# [Browser]why config_useragentprofile_url can not work

Tags: browser, frameworks, webkit

In Android ICS android\frameworks\base\core\res\res\values\config.xml, from the original comment, the config_useragentprofile_url can set browser's header ua profile link. After setting a value then try, from tcpdump log, we can not the ua profile link in header's request.
 The code maybe invalidate. There is anyone know why the code can not work? thanks

```
<!-- The URL that should be sent in an x-wap-profile header with an HTTP request,
     as defined in the Open Mobile Alliance User Agent Profile specification
     OMA-TS-UAProf-V2_0-20060206-A Section 8.1.1.1. If the URL contains a '%s'
     format string then that substring will be replaced with the value of
     Build.MODEL. The format string shall not be escaped. -->
<string name="config_useragentprofile_url" translatable="false"></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had  same  issue  on ics.  To enable it what you want, have to  implement uaprofile feature. Plz  refer  user-agent  at  websetting, jni, external network, lib core and so on. unfortunately, I can not share my codes due to office policy with operator contract. Good  luck

Comment: At last, we implement this by ourselves. In Tab.java,                     public void loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> headers) {                                 ...                                                           headers.put("x-wap-profile", HERMES_UAPURL);                          .... }   Thx!

Answer (score 0):

At last, we implement this by ourselves. In Tab.java,

```
    public void loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> headers) {                                 ...                                                                                          headers.put("x-wap-profile", HERMES_UAPURL);          



}
```

Thx!